# Use qmake variable in #include preprocessor command

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, preprocessor

I have a project coreApp using two libraries lib1 and lib2.

**Each lib has a file Version.h** specifying the lib version, **each in the library namespace**, example :

```
namespace lib1{
    static const QString Version = "1.2";
}
```

In my coreApp .pro I have :

```
LIB1_PATH_VAR = $$(LIB1_PATH) (LIB1_PATH is an environment variable storing the path to the root directory of lib1)
LIBS += -L$$LIB1_PATH_VAR/bin/ -l1
LIB2_PATH_VAR = $$(LIB2_PATH)
LIBS += -L$$LIB2_PATH_VAR/bin/ -l2
```

I want to do something like this in my main.cpp of coreApp :

```
#include "$$LIB1_PATH_VAR/Version.h"
#include "$$LIB2_PATH_VAR/Version.h"

std::cout<<lib1::Version<<std::endl;
std::cout<<lib2::Version<<std::endl;
```

It would allow me to be **independent from the library path** (in the code) while using classes that have the same name in both libraries (here Version.h).

Would it be possible ?

**Current Solution :**

```
INCLUDEPATH += LIB1_PATH/..
```

to my coreApp.pro
So that my main.cpp can look like this :

```
#include "path/to/lib1/Version.h"
#include "path/to/lib2/Version.h"

std::cout<<lib1::Version<<std::endl;
std::cout<<lib2::Version<<std::endl;
```

The problem is that the library path in written in the code, if I move the library to another location I have to change all my #include in the code

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible ?

Yes, qmake supports that kind of preprocessing using `QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES`. Some silly example code:

> my.pro

```
mysubst.input = myfile.cpp.in
mysubst.output = myfile.cpp
QMAKE_SUBSTITUTES += mysubst
```

> myfile.cpp.in

```
// all $$<expr> stuff is properly evaluated and substituted;
// !!IF / !!ELIF / !!ELSE / !!ENDIF processed as expected;
// quotes and backslashes must be escaped;
// anything else is passed through

#include <iostream>
!!IF !isEmpty(some_var)
#include \"$${some_var}\"
!!ENDIF
// more c++ code...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! does this mean that I need a myfile.cpp.in for each .cpp I have ??

Comment: @ElevenJune Of course, no. Only if you want qmake to generate that particular file from a template.